# How to extract the object individually from contour in an image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a PSD file that contains the ground-truth (contours of objects). I want to base on the contour to separate objects individually. I used below code but it only can extract the contour from the image (as shown below). How could I use the information to extract the object individually?

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage
psd = PSDImage.load('dna-0.psd')
group2 = psd.layers[0]
layer_image = group2.as_PIL()
layer_image.save('dna-0_contour.png')
```

The original file can be download at https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4yafn19qiuyqxi/dna-0.psd?dl=0
This is my current result

[image]

Comment: Does this simple approach work? Run a contour detection algorithm on the layer with contour daat. That's how you get "access" to individual objects. Then do this for every contour: run drawContours() algorithm to get the mask for each one of them.

Comment: Could you provide simple code? I will check it